# Which is 'right' versus 'left' rolling mean in R?

Tags: r, mean, moving-average, rolling-computation

If I want to calculate the previous `n` mean years with a lag of the current year, how would I accomplish this? Is it as simple as a "right" rolling mean window? Or is it a "left" rolling mean window? I'm not sure which window to use here.

**Sample Data**

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(year = c(1990:2010), 
                  x = rnorm(21))
dat$x_lag1 <- lag(dat$x, 1)
```

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, please close-as-duplicate

Comment: No obvious dupe that I see...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be easier to think in terms of offsets.  If you want a window of 3 then

- `align = "right"` corresponds to using a window based on offsets of -2, -1, 0, i.e. point before prior, prior and current point.  The current point is the rightmost end of the window.  Note that `rollapplyr` with an `r` on the end is the same as specifying `align = "right"`
- `align = "center"` corresponds to using a window based on offsets of -1, 0, 1, i.e. prior point current point and next point.  The current point is the center of the window.  This is the default for `align=` .
- `align = "left"` corresponds to using a window based on offsets of 0, 1, 2 i.e. current point, next point and point after that.  The current point is the leftmost point of the window.

`rollapply` allows one to use the `align=` specification or offset notation.  To use the latter for `width` specify a list containing a single vector defining the offsets.  (The actual specification of width is to specify a vector of widths, one for each element of the input or a list of offset vectors; however, in both cases they recycle so the usual case of specifying a single scalar width or a list containing a single offset vector are specifical cases.)

### window ending in current point

Below we use `align=` to take the mean of a window of 3 ending in the current point and also use offsets as an alternative.  We show both data frames and zoo objects.

We have omitted `fill=NA` for the zoo objects since they automatically align anyways so it is typically unnecessary to use it.

```
library(zoo)

r1 <- transform(dat, roll = rollapplyr(x, 3, mean, fill = NA))

r2 <- transform(dat, roll = rollapply(x, list(seq(-2, 0)), mean, fill = NA))

all.equal(r1, r2)
## [1] TRUE

z <- read.zoo(dat, FUN = identity)
r3 <- rollapplyr(z, 3, mean)

r4 <- rollmeanr(z, 3)

r5 <- rollapply(z, list(seq(-2, 0)), mean) # z from above

all.equal(r3, r4, r5)
## [1] TRUE
```

### window ending in prior point

If you want the 3 prior points, i.e. offsets -3, -2, -1, i.e. not the current point but the 3 points prior to that, then the following would work.  Note that `lag` in the last line requires a time series and should not be used with plain vectors.

```
# r6 is data frame
r6 <- transform(dat, roll = rollapply(x, list(-seq(3)), mean, fill = NA))

# r7, r8, r9 are zoo objects

r7 <- rollapply(z, list(-seq(3)), mean) # z from above

r8 <- stats::lag(rollapplyr(z, 3, mean), -1)

r9 <- stats::lag(rollmeanr(z, 3), -1)

all.equal(r7, r8, r9)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In short use `align = "right"` is the answer. The `align` specifies whether index of result be `left/center/right` aligned compared to rolling window of observations. If `width=3, align="right"` then two observations from left are passed along with current observation to `FUN` calculate value at index of current observation.

One can use `lag` of rolling(`align = "right"`) mean to get the `mean` for previous `n` observations excluding current observation. The below answer is based on `zoo::rollapply` and it calculate `mean` for previous `5` years.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(year = c(1990:2010), 
                  x = rnorm(21))

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
#Mean for previous 5 years can be calculated as:

dat$meanx <- lag(rollapply(dat$x, 5, mean, align = "right", fill=NA))

#Test result
dat[1:10,]
# year          x      meanx
# 1  1990 -0.6264538         NA
# 2  1991  0.1836433         NA
# 3  1992 -0.8356286         NA
# 4  1993  1.5952808         NA
# 5  1994  0.3295078         NA
# 6  1995 -0.8204684 0.12926990
# 7  1996  0.4874291 0.09046698
# 8  1997  0.7383247 0.15122413
# 9  1998  0.5757814 0.46601479
# 10 1999 -0.3053884 0.26211490
# so on
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than using `lag` use `rollapppy(x, 5, list(-seq(5)), mean, fill = NA)` . i.e. specify offsets -1, -2, -3, -4, -5.