# how can I rollmean with previous data, and compare with current data with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

say I have a data table as following

```
DT <- data.table(DATE = as.Date(1:10), X = 1:100)
```

(X shall be larger than 10 for there is only one obv. for each DATE, and nothing will come out)
how can I calculate each X with rollmean of previous k (say, 5) X?
the result shall be as following:

```
          DATE  X  rollmean
 1: 1970-01-02  1       NA
 2: 1970-01-03  2       NA
 3: 1970-01-04  3       NA
 4: 1970-01-05  4       NA
 5: 1970-01-06  5       NA
 6: 1970-01-07  6        3  # mean(1:5)
 7: 1970-01-08  7        4  # mean(2:6)
 8: 1970-01-09  8        5  # mean(3:7)
 9: 1970-01-10  9        6  # mean(4:8)
10: 1970-01-11 10        7  # mean(5:9)
```

I'd tried `zoo::rollmean`, but it seems only accepted "forward" direction, not the "backword" direction. Many thanks.

follow up question, even I would like to know if I wanna calculate previous 3 rows by 2 rows ahead? which is like, row8, X = 8, and I'd like to get the value of mean(3:5)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54740033/1989480

Comment: Thank, but I can't get the result, pls refer to my experiment as updated

Comment: try `DT[, RM := rollapplyr(X, list(-seq(5)), mean, fill = NA)]` and for followup qn: `DT[, RM := rollapplyr(X, list(-3L:-5L), mean, fill = NA)]`

Comment: thanks, it works for the toy example, however when used on my real case, it comes the error, while I hv change the data formate as the toy example. `Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)` Pls advise.

Comment: use `fill=NA_real_` instead of `fill=NA`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate moving average by specified grouping and deal with NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737762/how-to-calculate-moving-average-by-specified-grouping-and-deal-with-nas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data.table 1.12.0 there is new `frollmean` function, so you can do the following

```r
DT = data.table(DATE = as.Date(1:10, origin="1970-01-01"), X = 1:100)

ans = DT[1:10
         ][, rollmean:=shift(frollmean(X, 5))
           ][]
ans
#          DATE     X rollmean
# 1: 1970-01-02     1       NA
# 2: 1970-01-03     2       NA
# 3: 1970-01-04     3       NA
# 4: 1970-01-05     4       NA
# 5: 1970-01-06     5       NA
# 6: 1970-01-07     6        3
# 7: 1970-01-08     7        4
# 8: 1970-01-09     8        5
# 9: 1970-01-10     9        6
#10: 1970-01-11    10        7
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it using library zoo

```
library(zoo)
DT$rollmean <- rollmeanr(DT$X,5,fill=NA)
```

Comment: Hi, Hunaudkan, guess I misled you. I mean previous 5 obv. According your suggestion, I will get next 5 obv. Still thank you.

Comment: i am getting the same output as you have provided in the expected output, rollmean takes past 5 values not the forward values

Comment: thanks let me check again, I must have done something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same, but add align="right" to get only the current and the past observations.

It will be:

```html
library(zoo)
DT$rollmean <- rollmean(DT$X,5,fill=NA, align ="right")
```

as Grotendieck pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111935/which-is-right-versus-left-rolling-mean-in-r):

- **align = "right"** corresponds to using a window based on offsets of -2, -1, 0, i.e. point before prior, prior and current point. The current point is the rightmost end of the window. Note that rollapplyr with an r on the end is the same as specifying align = "right"
- **align = "center"** corresponds to using a window based on offsets of -1, 0, 1, i.e. prior point current point and next point. The current point is the center of the window. This is the default for align= .
- **align = "left"** corresponds to using a window based on offsets of 0, 1, 2 i.e. current point, next point and point after that. The current point is the leftmost point of the window.